# React Native: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native. Yesterday, I built a sample app and worked on it, but today when I tried doing the same, I'm getting this error:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

I tried this method available on the net but I got some other error with that:
 
**Method Tried:** In package.json I added {.... ,"type": "module",...}. 
 
**Error after adding this:**

```
<View style={styles.container}>
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:117:18)
at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:361:14)
at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:70:21)
```

Here is the code that I have:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { 
  StyleSheet, 
  Text, 
  View 
} from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Text here</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "orange",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Please let me know how could I fix this issue.

Comment: use import React from "react"; on top. of your component.

Comment: I did add import * as React from 'react';
Also tried import React from 'react'
but it still gave me errors